SQL Query inner join with specific data
SELECT players.`name`, multijobs.jobdata
FROM players
INNER JOIN multijobs
ON players.citizenid = multijobs.citizenid
SELECT * FROM multijobs WHERE jobdata LIKE '%police%';

So table multijobs does not show player names only citizen id's,
I just want to list the name of the player which is in the table players next to their jobdata which is in their multijobs table.

What is your question? It sounds like you need to extend the ON clause and add the condition. Or what is your problem? Write ...INNER JOIN multijobs ON players.citizenid = multijobs.citizenid AND multijobs.jobdata LIKE '%police%'

You can filter out the results using where clause after the Join
SELECT players.`name`, multijobs.jobdata
FROM players
INNER JOIN multijobs
ON players.citizenid = multijobs.citizenid
WHERE multijobs.jobdata LIKE '%police%'


or you can perform the filter directly on the Join when dealing with inner joins
SELECT players.`name`, multijobs.jobdata
FROM players
INNER JOIN multijobs
ON players.citizenid = multijobs.citizenid
and multijobs.jobdata LIKE '%police%'

Although filtering on Join in this case will return same results but if the join is for e.g left join then this might produce different results depending on what you need.

Your attempt is close. You only need one SELECT.
SELECT players.`name`, multijobs.jobdata
FROM players
INNER JOIN multijobs
    ON players.citizenid = multijobs.citizenid
WHERE multijobs.jobdata LIKE '%police%';

You can exclude the WHERE clause if you want to show the player name and jobdata for all players.

@Corevalence Please consider marking the accept answer flag to let others know this has been resolved.

Depending on the situation and context this might also need to be part of the ON clause. But for this query, WHERE is good.
